# Yup validation with one field but two possible options (OR)

Tags: formik, yup

I am trying to create an input that takes a string that will be used as the href value for a tag. The href can be a url OR an email (for mailto:).

It works if I just check for email, or if I just check for URL. However, I want to check for one or the other. I am looking through yup documentation but I can't find a way to do an OR.

I noticed that there is a when to test for another field but I'm not checking if another field is true or not, or use test but I also can't seem to get it to work.

```
const vSchema = yup.object().shape({
  text: yup.string().required(),
  href: yup
    .string()
    .email('Link must be a URL or email')
    .url('Link must be a URL or email')
    .required('Link is a required field'),
});
```

Answer (score 1):

test this

```js
yup.addMethod(yup.string, "or", function(schemas, msg) {
  return this.test({
    name: "or",
    message: "Please enter valid url or email." || msg,
    test: value => {
      if (Array.isArray(schemas) && schemas.length > 1) {
        const resee = schemas.map(schema => schema.isValidSync(value));
        return resee.some(res => res);
      } else {
        throw new TypeError("Schemas is not correct array schema");
      }
    },
    exclusive: false
  });
});
```